# Does the keys in internationalisation rails behaves different if they are of different case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

The example is from rails docs:

```
en:
 hello: "Hello world"
```

Are the both different. Does the case of the keys matters?

```
en:
 Hello: "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, case of the keys matters.

check example,

define variables in en.yml

```
en:
  hello: "hello world"
  Hello: "HELLO WORLD"
```

and access it from console as

```
2.2.1 :001 > I18n.t('hello')
 => "hello world" 
2.2.1 :002 > I18n.t('Hello')
 => "HELLO WORLD"
```

Please check [Rails Internationalization](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Really appreciated :)